# Concatenating from a table by filtering first

Tags: google-sheets

Consider the table below:

```
       A             B            C        D
 1 category      subcategory    company  amount
 2 health care   diagnostics     AA       100
 3 health care   diagnostics     AB        50
 4 materials     mining          BA        75
 5 financials    banks           CA        30
 6 financials    insurers        CB        35
 7 financials    banks           CC        10
 8 financials    banks           CD        40
 9 financials    hedge fund      CE         5
10 health care   equipment       DA        50
```

I want to (1) concatenate the companies for each category and (2) return the aggregated amount.

```
      A              B              C
1 category       companies       amount
2 health care    AA AB DA          200     <--- 100 + 50 + 50
3 materials      BA                 75
4 financials     CA CB CC CD CE    120
```

I am aware that (2) can easily be done by using a pivot table, but (1) is not supported by pivots. So given the excel below, what formula do I need in `B1` and `C1` to get the desired output?

```
      A              B              C
1 category       
2 health care    
3 materials      
4 financials
```

I have looked into `concatenate()`, which is needed here, but I don't see how I can give arguments to that function, like pseudo:

```
=concatenate(C2:C10; "where (A:A) = 'health care')
```

Who can help me out?

Comment: While you got a formula that works, I would suggest looking into [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) - as the formula below seems to me to rely on a few hacks of the query function, and can be quite tough to maintain IMO. With Apps Script you would have a lot more flexibility and portability. That said, if formulas work for you then power to you, just know that these problems seem to me to be on the limit of what formulas can do, and still be readable/maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({QUERY({A:D}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col4) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col4)'amount'", 1), {"companies"; 
 TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({A:D, C:C}, 
 "select max(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col5"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)))}}, 
 "select Col1,Col3,Col2", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's amazing and seeing your solution I'm not ashamed I couldn't come up with it oO

Comment: I'm trying to unravel what you are doing, but might come back with a question or 2 :)

Comment: I'm trying to unravel what you are doing. If we assume that the `amount` for `BA` would be `0` (instead of `75`), and in the output table I only want to see categories `where amount > 0` (so this would give the output as you have, but minus the last row), where do I then add this condition?

Comment: And secondly, to also group by `subcategory`, I have added this in both queries (`group by Col1, Col2`) but I don't see how to add the column `subcategory` to the output table (I added `Col2` to the select but this does not work --- it is grouping by but no 4th column appears in the output table)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jhtBQpYE_9hyzPjVGF6vBY6QPEfjcyIUTlFOBkXlpw4/edit#gid=0